# jQuery Not Implementing Requested CSS change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Function is as follows:

```
function background() {
                Object.keys(newImages).map((key) => newImages[key] = 'url(' + '"' + newImages[key] + '"' + ')');
                switch (city.file.icon) {
                    case "11d":
                        $("body").css('background-image', newImages.rain);
                        document.body.style.color = white;
                        break;
                    case "09d":
                        $("body").css('background-image', newImages.rain);
                        break;
                    case "10d":
                        $("body").css('background-image', newImages.rain);
                        break;
                    case "13d":
                        $("body").css('background-image', newImages.rain);
                        break;
                    case "50d":
                        $("body").css('background-image', newImages.rain);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

...and the problem is that the request to change the body's background isn't occurring on the function call. Thoughts?

EDIT:

```
function weatherData() {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                let data = {
                    city: 'q=' + fixInput('city')
                };
                xhr.open('POST', weather.queryImperialGetString() + data.city), true);

                xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        let obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        let file = new weather.jsonFileConstructor(obj);
                        city.file = file;
                        document.getElementById('div_1').innerHTML = weather.showIcon(city.file.weatherIcon);
                        document.getElementById('div_2').innerHTML = "Current Temp: " + city.file.currentTemp;
                        document.getElementById('div_3').innerHTML = "High: " + city.file.hiTemp;
                        document.getElementById('div_4').innerHTML = "Low: " + city.file.loTemp;
                        document.getElementById('div_5').innerHTML = "Humidity: " + city.file.humidity;
                        document.getElementById('div_6').innerHTML = "Weather Type: " + city.file.weatherType;
                        document.getElementById('div_7').innerHTML = "Weather Description: " + city.file.weatherDescription;
                        document.getElementById('div_8').innerHTML = "Windspeed: " + city.file.windSpeed;
                        document.getElementById('div_9').innerHTML = "Wind Direction: " + city.file.windDegree;
                        document.getElementById('div_10').innerHTML = "Pressure: " + city.file.pressure;
                        background();
                    };
                };
                xhr.send();
            };
```

...and I'm just saying this stuff down here because StackOverflow won't accept the edit without more words...

Comment: Are you sure this `city.file.icon` is not null or undefined?

Comment: Where is `city` at here?

Comment: City is loaded with data from a JSON constructor earlier on.

Comment: I'm gonna edit the main post so you can see.

Comment: I use the benefit of object storage and manipulation by reference to throw the data in there just in case I need it for something else later on.

Comment: @AndrewRamshaw Have you checked for any errors in Developer Tools console? Also, have you tried inspecting the page elements and check if body tag contains any background-image css added?

Comment: Doesn't say anything about errors, and parts of it work in Firefox but not Chrome. The body just has a background of blue.

Comment: ...and for some reason my query string function works in one browser and not the other and they're both up to date.

Comment: Also wanted to add that I was having issues before the background color for body was blue.